# How to remove all contents of database using MongoAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, mongoalchemy

As title suggests, I want to remove all contents of the database. I'm making an application in Python using Flask and MongoAlchemy for database. I have the class **People** which models the documents. The structure is:

```
class People(db.Document):
    Name = db.StringField()
    Age = db.IntField()
    Password = db.StringField()
    Vms = db.AnythingField()
```

With the **remove** method I can delete only one document at once, based on the name or other detail, but I want to be able to delete them all at once.

This is my function for deleting a document, based on name.

```
def delete_document(name):
    x = People.query.filter(People.Name == name).first()
    x.remove()
```

Where People is the reference to the model class.

Comment: I don't think people will be interested in your class, more likely they will be interested in how you initialize and communicate with the db itself

Comment: @JackParkinson: I see. I edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is a easy way, using one of the built-in methods from Query class, **remove_all**. With the **remove_all** method you can get all the results from database in a list, and after that you can call the **remove** method on every instance. The code is posted below. Not sure if there is a more efficient way of doing this, so feel free to post it.

```
def deleteAll():
    x = People.query.all()
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        x[i].remove()
```